# Printing debug output in Windows programs

Tags: windows, winapi, logging

I am starting to do some work with the Windows API. However, I noticed that you can not use functions like printf if you have a windowed application. What is the standard way of printing debug and logging information? Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print to the debug output window in a Win32 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I normally use `OutputDebugString()`, the API is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362.aspx).  While running the application you can then view the output of this function with [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from SysInternals or in the Visual Studio output window while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Options:

1. Make your own class that logs to a file
2. Create a [list view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774737(VS.85).aspx) or [edit control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775458(v=VS.85).aspx), and append text to it
3. Use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx)
4. Create a [console window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85).aspx)
5. Windows [Event Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968803(v=VS.85).aspx) (not for general logging)

Comment: Adrian your answer is by far more complete, I think that you have not been chosen for the answer because an example is missing.