# how to log in win32 c++ to the visual studio output window?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

My log4net is logging to the visual studio output windows but what code can I use in the C++ win32 code to do the same as I need to debug the C++ and can't seem to step through it at all and logging would be useful in production as well anyways.  I added

```
wprintf(L"Registering hook handler\n");
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  It has been years since I have done C++ as well, let alone win32 C++.

Comment: `OutputDebugString`; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`OutputDebugString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me for some reason :(.  or maybe I don't know how to open the right output view.  I only see an Immediate View tab and an Output tab and it doesn't go to either of those.

Comment: You need to be running with the debugger. If you do, it should show up in the Output window when Debug is selected in the pull down.

Comment: I was running with the Debugger(the little Play icon with Debug in the pulldown).  Does it matter that the my main project is C# and one of the other projects is C++?  I thought it would be sucked in and the whole solution run in debug mode?  Maybe I am missing something here.