# how to enable debugging of visual studio C++ called from C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi

(Modifying the question)I have a windows form app in C# which calls into some C++, and I need to add logs that log to some window in visual studio(output tab or the 'immediate window' tab....I don't care which.

I had this post but none of those solutions worked.....
[how to log in win32 c++ to the visual studio output window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059675/how-to-log-in-win32-c-to-the-visual-studio-output-window)

A comment below mentions I can turn debugging on, but there is no "debug tab", there are no tabs whatsoever so I am not sure how to enable debugging in the following picture...

[image]

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick "Enable unmanaged debugging".  Short from output, you can now also *debug* the C++ code, rather a better approach than writing debugging output.  A console window is simple, Application tab, change Output type to "Console Application".

Comment: No, that answer is independant of the subsystem in use and can be used by console/gui apps alike. Marked as a duplicate.

Comment: really, because I of course tried those solutions but they didn't work for me :(

Comment: I don't see how to set Enable unmanaged debugging either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see how to set Enable unmanaged debugging either?

On your C# EXE project, not your C++ project.  Right-click the C# project, Properties, Debug tab:

[image]