# c++ console in a non-console application project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm working on a windows application in C++, and I'd like to use `cout` for debugging purposes.
It seems that the effects of `cout` are hidden, is there a configuration option that will allow a console window to open with my debug information?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app

Comment: @Sergey: No, that's not a dupe. That's asking about writing with `OutputDebugString`. That doesn't/won't make `cout` usable (though it is, IMO, a perfectly valid *alternative*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of reasonable options. One is to rename your entrypoint from `WinMain` to `main`, so it'll be built as a console application. That can still use things like `RegisterClass` and `CreateWindow` just fine.

The obvious alternative would be to use `OutputDebugString` instead of `cout`. The output from that will show up in a debugger, or any number of programs built specifically to display what it produces (basically mini-debuggers that just don't provide other debugging capabilities).

A third solution I'd consider less reasonable is to call `AllocConsole` to allocate a console, then write to it. If you don't mind doing all your writing with Windows-native console functions (`WriteFile`, `WriteConsoleOutput`, etc.) that's fine. Unfortunately, it won't initialize the C++ streams to work with the console, so you'll need to either open file streams pointing the console, or else find and use the (undocumented) function that initializes the streams library for the console. While this can be made to work, you end up doing extra work to write non-portable code, and little (if any) advantage to make up for it (and in this case, "non-portable" can include not even working with other versions of the same compiler, at least if you invoke the library's initialization function).

Comment: Redirecting `cout` is quite portable.  I think you'd end up with a grand total of two lines of Windows-specific code -- the one calling `AllocConsole`, and the one containing the special filename `"CONOUT$"`.  I wouldn't consider `OutputDebugString` a viable alternative at all, since it doesn't support any formatting, let alone compatibility with functions designed for `iostreams`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: A front end that formats with `vsprintf`, then uses `OutputDebugString` is trivial. A streabuf whose `overflow` uses `OutputDebugstring` isn't *quite* as trivial, but still not exactly rocket science.

Comment: Using `vsprintf` is only trivial if you don't care about possible buffer overflow.

Comment: @BenVoigt: How often is that a problem for debugging output? At least in my experience with it (admittedly limited -- only 3 decades or so) the answer to that is "never."

Comment: Depends on what you're debugging, I suppose.  If you had a problem where an input string wasn't correctly NUL-terminated, or a file used the wrong line ending and therefore was treated as one massive line instead of many short ones, I can easily imagine where data sent to the debug output could be much much larger than designed.  After all, debug information is most useful when inputs differ from expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Your answers and comments led me to find this library which handles allocConsole for me.    

http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2):

To add a console window to a GUI application, you can use the [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Then you just need to open the special file name `"CONOUT$"` and attach your streams to it (`cout`, `cerr`, etc)

See [this explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted answers are actually not what you are looking for. You say you need it only for debugging, not for release. Your best options are:

a) redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file and then inspect the file. This you can set in the VS project `Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments`: you should enter `>out.txt 2>&1`. This will output both `stdout` and `stderr` to `out.txt`

b) set your debug (you say you need it only for debugging) configuration `Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem` to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`. Then you can run the project with `F5`, but it will hide the console window when your application finishes. If you run it with `Ctrl+F5` (but then you will not have debugger attached), then it will not be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to start a Console application from scratch:

In VisualStudio, **File** > **New Project**.  Select **Win32 Console Application**.  Select various options and create the new project.

Note that although it says *Win32* Console Application, you can create x64 builds without restriction.

At this point you have an application shell.  If you already have code and you want to bring it in to this new project, simply do **Project** > **Add Existing Item...** and select the files to include in the project.

Comment: I believe this is no-go solution for an existing non-console project. There are much better solutions available.

Answer (score 0):

Managing a console from a GUI program is horribly messy, and I suggest you do it another way. For instance, if you need to see the messages in real time, display them in a window; if not, write them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

just use `OutputDebugString()` but remember to either set your character set to multibyte, or if you don't want to do that, you could write your code like this:

```
// with multibyte character set:

   OutputDebugString("Failed to do something");

// without multibyte character set:

   OutputDebugString(L"Failed to do something");
```