# how to see the printf when I debug the windows program?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ console in a non-console application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085025/c-console-in-a-non-console-application-project)

I am debugging windows program which started with winmain. There are smome printf inside, I am wondering if I can view the printf output somewhere? Do I need some special tools?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using VC++ you can use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display output in the IDE.

something like:

```
wchar_t buffer[512]
wsprintf(buffer, L"Value is %d\n", value);
OutputDebugString(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);
// your printf()

fclose(stdout);
FreeConsole();
```