# Visual Studio 2019 - How to move debug console to bottom panel?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have the Visual Studio 2019 community version and the debug console is a separate window. How can I attach it to the bottom panel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanna say your actually talking about the `Output` window.
From the menu select `View->Output` of from keyboard  <kbd>Ctrl+W,O</kbd> .

The output window is docable like you wanted.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/R6zM4TX.png im trying to display the output on the bottom panel instead of a different window but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Console.Writeline("string data"); in C#...also Debug.Writeline("degub data");

Comment: for instance when I run ```cout << "hello world"```; it displays that inside the black window.

Comment: What language...C++ ?

Comment: yeah its for C++

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333527/how-do-i-print-to-the-debug-output-window-in-a-win32-app